# Is fail2ban slowing my system or iptables?

Tags: nginx, iptables, fail2ban

I have a server (*VPS*) with the following services:

- email server (postfix/dovecot)
- dns server (bind9)
- http server (nginx)

Fail2ban creates a lot of entries in *iptables* and this causes the server to become very slow and even sometimes it becomes unreachable and I have to login via the console and flush *iptables* before I can connect to the server. The used jails are shown below:

- Jail list:    `dovecot, named-refused, nginx-botsearch, nginx-http-auth, nginx-limit-req, php-url-fopen, postfix, postfix-auth, recidive`

95% of bans are triggered by *postfix* jail.
I reduced *iptables* size by setting *recidive* jail with :
`bantime  = 7200`
`findtime = 3600`
`maxretry = 5`
, the system slowness slightly improved but still not enough.
My question : - is fail2ban to blame for this slowness? or iptables itself?   In a previous project, I had no fail2ban installed and I used *iptables* with many entries (more entries than what my actual fail2ban creates) and the system was fast.

I appreciate any advice on how can I deal with this fail2ban issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them are to blame. Fail2Ban monitors your logs - so if there is a lot of logging, Fail2Ban will have to parse more text. IPtables performs linear search over the list of rules - it is not possible to use binary search as this will break the logic. So the more rules - the slower IPtables will be.

You should check the `usedns` and `banaction` settings in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`. DNS queries may be slow and you may want to try `iptables-ipset-proto4` instead of `iptables-multiport` as an action.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked as you advised. The situation didn't improve. I am considering removing fail2ban and use only iptables.

Comment: You can also try CrowdSec - https://dev.to/jeand/crowdsec-an-open-source-modernized-collaborative-fail2ban-371i (https://danielmiessler.com/study/crowdsec/)

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I will have a look at CrowdSec (it is the first time to hear about it :) )

Comment: Another reason for the slowness could be if Fail2Ban is not using the `inotify` mechanism when watching for file changes (new entries in the logs).

Comment: python3-pyinotify is already installed and should take care of new entries of logs. I found this as well: *https://websavers.ca/improve-fail2ban-io-performance*

Answer (score 1):

You can add `tail` after the `logpath` so fail2ban will only read from the end of the file. Otherwise, if you reboot there can be a very long pause while fail2ban reads huge log files.

```
logpath = /var/log/yourfile tail
```